# How to subscribe to response of node server

Tags: node.js, angular

I am trying to subscribe to my node server reslut and i tried following
my ts,

```
 .subscribe(
        response => {
            if (response.json().result == 'success') {
                this.toastr.success('Loggedin successfully');
                this.router.navigate(['/demo/profile']);

            }
            else {
                this.toastr.error('Email or Password is wrong');
            }
        });
```

my server response,

```
  {
  "status": "success",
  "result": [
    {
      "profile_id": 1,
      "firstname": "Sachin",
      "repeatpassword": null,
      "type": null,
      "connection_status": null,
      "relation_id": null
    }
  ]
}
```

can someone help me

Comment: What is your problem? Any errors etc? In your `if` you're checking for `response.json().result`, but in your JSON, the `status` field holds the value ...

Comment: i subscribed in the above way for my success case it is not working

Comment: `response.json().status == 'success'`

Comment: it is getting success even  i give wrong  credentials

Answer (score 1):

Change your subscribe code as below :

```
subscribe(
        response => {
            if (response.json().status == 'success') {
                this.toastr.success('Loggedin successfully');
                this.router.navigate(['/demo/profile']);

            }
            else {
                this.toastr.error('Email or Password is wrong');
            }
        });
```

Comment: it is getting success even if i give wrong credentials

Comment: you need to check your API response when wrong credentials is returned.